# Adding AngularJS 1 with TypeScript into existing Asp.Net Mvc 4 web application

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, typescript

Having Asp.Net MVC 4 Web Application.
By adding `ng-app` and `ng-view` in one of `MVC` Views I was able to embed `AngularJS 1` single page application in it. 
Customer hard requirement avoid using `Angular 2`.

Would like to move all JS to TypeScript (never did TS in Visual Studio).

Is there any standard approach in Visual Studio for that?

Would like to avoid any additional task runners (like grunt, browserify and etc.)

Should I do something like:

1. Rename all *.js to *.ts
2. Adding required `typings`
3. Prebuild event must transpilling TypeScript into JavaScript (dist folder)
4. `BundleConfig` must collect all generated JS (from dist)

Is that a right direction?

Thanks in advance!